# How to get specific text from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get text from an array except year,month,date using javascript.I do not know how do it.

```js
var arr = [
  "power-still-rate-19.08.22", 
  "main-still-rate-19.08.22", 
  "oil-power-rate-19.08.22", 
  "oil-mill-rate-19.7.2"
];
var result;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result = arr[i].remove('?????????');
}
console.log(result);

//result should be like = power-still-rate,main-still-rate,oil-power-rate ;
```

Comment: Sometime date will be like 19-8-2.So How we can do in this condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split, slice and join

```js
var arr = ["power-still-rate-19.08.22", "main-still-rate-19.08.22", "oil-power-rate-19.08.22","oil-mill-rate-19.7.2"];
var result = arr.map(item => item.split("-").slice(0,-1).join("-"))
console.log(result);
```

Split, pop and join

```js
var arr = ["power-still-rate-19.08.22", "main-still-rate-19.08.22", "oil-power-rate-19.08.22","oil-mill-rate-19.7.2"];
var result = arr.map(item => { let res = item.split("-"); res.pop(); return res.join("-") })
console.log(result);
```

No map:

```js
var arr = ["power-still-rate-19.08.22", "main-still-rate-19.08.22", "oil-power-rate-19.08.22","oil-mill-rate-19.7.2"];
var result = arr.join("").split(/-\d{1,}\.\d{1,}\.\d{1,}/);
result.pop(); // last empty item, not needed if you do not want an array just join with comma
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can we do without map?

Comment: I have updated my question..Sometime date will be like 19-8-2.   month and date will be single digit so how we can do on that condition?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to match non-digit characters from the start of the string, followed by `-` and a digit:

```js
const input = ["power-still-rate-19.08.22", "main-still-rate-19.08.22", "oil-power-rate-19.08.22","oil-mill-rate-19.7.2"];
const output = input.map(str => str.match(/\D+(?=-\d)/)[0]);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split on -` ,splicing the last element which is the date and `joining on -`

```js
var arr=["power-still-rate-19.08.22","main-still-rate-19.08.22","oil-power-rate-19.08.22"];
    arr.forEach(function(e,i){
    arr[i]=e.split('-').splice(0,3).join('-')
    })
    console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove certain pattern from string using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```js
const input = ["power-still-rate-19.08.22", "main-still-rate-19.08.22", "oil-power-rate-19.08.22","oil-mill-rate-19.7.2"];
const res = input.map(str => str.replace(/-\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/, ''));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove back string by using `slice` function and join them with `join` function.

```js
var arr = ["power-still-rate-19.08.22", "main-still-rate-19.08.22", "oil-power-rate-19.08.22","oil-mill-rate-19.7.2"];
var result = arr.map(str => str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf('-'))).join(',');
console.log(result);
```